# Where does WhatsApp save audio files?

Tags: whatsapp

Where are audio files shared through WhatsApp saved on the phone? Can I access it through the gallery?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know whatsapp audio files are stored internaly in the app, so you can't save them to your phone public storage.